# Late 90's or early 00's cartoon (maybe anime) with a boy, I think called Kenshin, who unwittingly causes a curse on himself

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching a cartoon on Cartoon Network in the late 90s or early 2000s on Cartoon Network. I think it is a sci-fi/fantasy anime (not too sure, it could just be an American cartoon). I think the protagonist is called Kenshin. I could be wrong, but he unwittingly causes a curse. It also had witches, some tried to protect him, while others tried to get him.

I have tried searching on Google for years now to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't seem to have witches nor does it seem to be sci-fi/fantasy, this might be [Rurouni Kenshin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin). Other than that, it matches very well.

The anime aired on Toonami in 2003 (i.e. on Cartoon Network). The main character is Himura Kenshin. The show's [wiki](https://kenshin.fandom.com/wiki/Himura_Kenshin) says this about his scar:

> According to his allies during his days in the Isshi Shishi, this scar was said to have constantly bled and never healed as the mark of a curse for having slain an innocent person.